# Determine Last Modified Date of a card in Trello

Tags: trello, search

In Trello, is there a search term possible for determining the last modified date of a card?

I was hoping to be able to search for similar to:

> is:archived last_modified:2

to find cards which are archived and last_modified more than 2 days ago.

The [documentation](https://trello.com/docs/api/search/index.html) lists an `actions_since` argument, but I'm not clear on what this does.

Answer (score 2):

To select all archived cards edited more than 2 days ago you can use:

```
is:archived -edited:2
```

The *edited* operator selects cards that have been edited within the time specific. Numeric values are interpreted as days. Additional selectors are :week and :month. The minus sign (-) inverts the behavior of that operator.

In this case *-edited:2* means "Edited more than two days ago".

From http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1145462-searching-for-cards-all-boards-